Функции, возвращающие интерфейсы
Есть простой тестовый код:
program intftest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  ITest = Interface
  ['{F76722CE-6B62-49FE-8D5E-8646558DE528}']
    function GetRefCount: Integer;
  end;

  TTest = class(TInterfacedObject, ITest);

  function GetTest: ITest;
  begin
    Result := TTest.Create;
    WriteLn(Result.GetRefCount); // 1
  end;

var
  Test: ITest;
begin
  try
    Test := GetTest;
    WriteLn(Test.GetRefCount);   // 2
    Test := nil;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.

Вопрос: что я делаю не так, почему по выходу из функции GetTest() значение Test.RefCount = 2? И как в этом случае корректно уничтожить объект?..

Всё делаете так, интерфейсный объект будет удалён автоматически, занулять руками его не надо. Счётчик показывает 2 из-за какого-то сайд-эффекта, связанного с использованием глобальной переменной. Компилятор вероятно создал невидимую переменную, которая и держит ещё одну ссылку. Если весь код поместить внутрь функции, то счётчик будет показывать 1, как и ожидалось. В любом случае, при выходе из области видимости счётчик в итоге обнулится и объект будет уничтожен.

Проблема в том, что мне надо удалить этот объект после использования. При присваивании nil переменной он не удаляется. При сохранении ссылки на объект и явном вызове Free он тоже не удаляется, потому что RefCount > 0... При этом, если заменить функцию на процедуру с параметром procedure GetTest(out Result: ITest);, то всё работает как надо. Похоже на какой-то баг. И, кстати, отладчик показывает что счётчик увеличивается с 1 до 2 в момент выхода из функции. Т.е. присваивание Test := Result увеличивает счётчик ссылок, а выход Result за пределы видимости его не уменьшает.

Тогда просто не используйте интерфейсы, если вам надо ручное управление временем жизни объекта. Описанное поведение не баг: как я уже писал выше - компилятор сохраняет ссылку во временной переменной, которую он заводит для своих внутренних нужд.

Увы, не использовать интерфейсы я не могу, т.к. я передаю его из dll, а там не много вариантов.
